# Storing spaCy annotations and updating them

Tags: javascript, python, flask, visualization, spacy

Currently, I have a custom NER spaCy model which I use to annotate around 6000 full-text articles. Currently, I serve up the annotated articles to the user based on ID, and the user can add/remove, edit the annotations, and then download the file as a JSON for me to finetune the model. I am looking to change the workflow so that I can run the model on all articles and save the annotations in the db in an article-paragraph-sentence-annotation(start-end) format and serve it up from the db to the user. The storing in a Db and serving up the annotations highlighted in the article format is something I am not able to figure out. Currently, I am using Flask server and using javascript for the annotation tool for the user. Any advice/suggestions on how to tackle the problem would be appreciated.